# Status bar is overlap to navigationbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

In my app , status bar is overlapping to navigation bar. I tried a lot but did not get success.

[image]

Here, in color green is my navigation bar. Problem is in only `iOS 6.0` and `iOS 6.1`. It is working perfect in `iOS 7.0` and `iOS 7.1`. Navigation bar displayed half in `iOS 6.0` and in `iOS 6.1`. Status bar is overlapping here

Comment: Have you hide and show the status  bar?

Comment: Yes , at first screen i hide the status bar and in the next screen i show it .

Comment: before post your question search on stackoverflow or google. plenty of answers available in stackoverflow

Comment: @Birju: codercat is right.you can easily find solution on stackoverflow.

Comment: So before next screen  show status bar

Comment: @codercat if he cant then you should find the link for him.. i dnt think so he just post the question

Comment: I got the solution :) Thnx codercat